# How to add hive auxiliary jars to Dataproc cluster

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

When you start a hive session in Dataproc you can add jars that live in a gcs bucket.
`add jar gs://my-bucket/serde.jar;`

I don't want to have to add all the jars I need each time I start a hive session so I tried adding the jar paths to hive-site.xml in the hive.aux.jars.path property.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
  <value>gs://my-bucket/serde.jar</value>
</property>
```

Then I get hit with this error when trying to start a hive session.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://gs, expected: file:///`

Is there a way to add custom jars that live in a gcs bucket to the hive classpath or would I have to copy the jars from my bucket and update hive.aux.jars.path each time I create a dataproc cluster?

*edit
Even after adding the below property and restarting hive I still get the same error.

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.exim.uri.scheme.whitelist</name>
    <value>hdfs,pfile,gs</value>
    <final>false</final>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Hive bug ([HIVE-18871](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18871)) - `hive.aux.jars.path` supports only local paths in Hive 3.1 and lower.

Workaround will be to use [Dataproc initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) that copies jars from GCS to the same local FS path on all Dataproc cluster nodes and specify this local path as a value of the `hive.aux.jars.path` property.

### Update

HIVE-18871 fix was [back ported to Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#February_26_2021) 1.3+ images, so you can use GCS URIs in the `hive.aux.jars.path` property with new Dataproc images that have this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to set property `hive.exim.uri.scheme.whitelist` to whitelist gcs uri.

So in your case, while creating a Dataproc cluster, set properties

```
hive.aux.jars.path = gs://my-bucket/serde.jar
hive.exim.uri.scheme.whitelist = hdfs,pfile,gs
```

Comment: I tried adding hive.exim.uri.scheme.whitelist to hive-site.xml and still got the same error after restarting the hive server.